# array_item[] = $file what does this do?

Tags: php, readdir

I have been following a tutorial on readdir(), is_dir() etc involved in setting up a small image gallery based on folders and files on my FTP. I was wondering what the $directorys[] = $file; part does specifically?

```
while( $file= readdir( $dir_handle ) )      
{
        if( is_dir( $file ) ){              
            $directorys[] = $file;          
        }else{                              
            $files[] = $file;               
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It pushes an item to the array, instead of `array_push`, it would only push one item to the array.

Using `array_push` and `$array[] = $item` works the same, but it's not ideal to use `array_push` as it's suitable for pushing multiple items in the array.

Example:

```
Array (
)
```

After doing this `$array[] = 'This works!';` or `array_push($array, 'This works!')` it will appear as this:

```
Array (
   [0] => This works!
)
```

Also you can push arrays into an array, like so:

```
$array[] = array('item', 'item2');

Array (
   [0] => Array (
             [0] => item
             [1] => item2
          )
)
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot and thanks for the other replies.

Answer (score 3):

`$directory` is an array.

The code

`$directory[] = $file`

adds `$file` to the end of `$directory` array. This is the same as

`array_push($directory, $file)`.

More info at [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) at phpdocs

Comment: So your code reads in a list of files/folders, and sorts them into two arrays: $directorys and $files

Answer (score 2):

$file will contain the name of the item that was scanned. In this case, the use of is_dir($file) allows you to check that $file in the current directory is a directory or not.

Then, using the standard array append operator [], the $file name or directory name is added to a $files/$directorys array...

Answer (score 1):

It adds the directory to the `directory` array :)

```
    if( is_dir( $file ) ){              
        $directorys[] = $file; // current item is a directory so add it to the list of directories       
    }else{                              
        $files[] = $file; // current item is a file so add it to the list of files
    }
```

However if you use PHP 5 I really suggest using a [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php).

BTW naming that `$file` is really bad, since it isn't always a file.

Answer (score 0):

It creates a new array element at the end of the array and assigns a value to it.